# Powershell named parameters error

Tags: powershell, arguments

I'm tring to do the following:

```
$Feature = "OWAEnabled"
Set-CasMailbox Admin -$($Feature) $False
```

But i get each time this error:

```
Set-CASMailbox : Es wurde kein Positionsparameter gefunden, der das Argument "-OWAEnabled:True" akzeptiert.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:2
+  set-casmailbox Administrator -$($Feature):$True
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-CASMailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.SetCASMailbox
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, though not the prettiest:

```
$Feature = "OWAEnabled"
$c = "Set-CasMailbox Admin -$($Feature):`$False"
Invoke-Expression $c
```

Comment: What version of Exchange are you running?

Comment: Exchange 2010 14.03.0174.001

Comment: Set-CasMailbox Administrator -OWAEnabled:$True This works well